# Vim normal command using variable value

Tags: vim

I need to do the following:

- Set a variable `temp` to some value (say 100).
- Go somewhere to increase a number by `temp` *for a range of lines*.
- Update `temp` to be +100.
- Repeat

I started by setting the value 100 to temp using `let temp=100`.

I then figure out the following ex command that I can apply to a line: `:execute "normal! ". temp. "^A"` this will take temp and increase the number by `temp` for the current line.

Unfortunately, this will not work when I visually select a range of lines and then hit `:` to apply a command to all the lines selected.

How can I achieve the same but for a range of lines?

Here is an example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Should become

```
101
102
103
104
105
```

Then I will update the temp to `let temp=temp + 100` and repeat for the next block and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: In this case you could just prepend `10` in visual block mode. But I guess you also have numbers >9?

Comment: Yes, they are 100 per group and there are at least 25 such groups.

Comment: @John, you might find my answer interesting in this case but in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question directly, `:help :execute` is what is blocking you for two reasons:

- `:execute` doesn't accept a range,
- `:execute` is not necessary to begin with.

The following command does the job without `:execute`:

```
:[range]normal! <C-r>=temp<CR><C-v><C-a><CR>
```

Breakdown:

- `[range]` would be `'<,'>` after a visual selection.
- `:help :normal` executes the given macro in normal mode.
- `:help c_ctrl-r` inserts the content of the given register in the command line.
- `:help "=` is the expression register, which returns an evaluated expression.
- `temp` is the expression to evaluate, so `<C-r>=temp<CR>` inserts the content of the variable `temp`.
- `<C-v><C-a>` inserts a literal `^A`.
- `<CR>` executes the command.

But that's a lot to type so a simple mapping seems more appropriate in this case:

```
xnoremap <expr> <key> temp . '<C-a>'
```

Breakdown:

- `:help :xnoremap` creates a visual mode mapping.
- `:help <expr>` makes it an expression mapping, where the actual RHS is evaluated *at runtime*.
- `<key>` is what key you want to press.
- `temp . '<C-a>'` is your expression, which concatenates the current value of `temp` with `<C-a>` to obtain `100<C-a>`, `200<C-a>`, etc..

Usage:

1. Set `temp` to the desired value:

   ```
   :let temp = 100
   ```
2. Select some lines:

   ```
   v<motion>
   ```
3. Increment the first number of each line:

   ```
   <key>
   ```
4. Change the value of `temp`:

   ```
   :let temp += 100
   ```
5. Move to next block and select some lines:

   ```
   <motion>
   v<motion>
   ```
6. Increment the first number of each line:

   ```
   <key>
   ```

---

However, the manual way would go like this:

```
v<motion>    " visually select the desired lines
100<C-a>     " increment the first number on each line by 100
```

then:

```
<motion>
v<motion>
200<C-a>     " increment the first number on each line by 200
```

and so on… so I'm not sure what's be the benefit of introducing variables, `:normal`, etc., here.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a workaround, if no one knows a better way.

I recorded a macro `b` to run `execute "normal! " . temp . "^A"` on the current line. Then recorded another macro `a` that will go and visually select all the lines in the group interested and run `:'<,'>norm @b` this will apply that operation on every line, then before ending the macro `@a`, I also set `let temp=temp+100`.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use global command to do the work, it accepts the range.

```
:'<,'>g/./execute "normal! ". temp. "^A"
```